# JavaRMI creates a single ServerSocket when some object is Exported?

Tags: java, rmi, serversocket

I am new in Java and JavaRMI so a have some doubts about how its works, see below:

```
public interface Something implements Remote {...}

public SomeStub extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Something {...}
```

Every time when I create and bind (`registry.rebind(...)`) one object of `SomeStub` I am creating a new `ServerSocket` to listen calls only for this object?

Example:

```
registry.rebind("...", new obj1);
registry.rebind("...", new obj2);
registry.rebind("...", new obj3).
```

2) So if the question 1 is true, is better use just only one stub of this object and threads to avoid create lots of serversockets?

PS: I am using the default serversocket and socket factories provided by the JavaRMI.

Comment: `new obj1` and friends do not compile. Please clarify.

Comment: Oh sorry my example is just trying to show the idea of one server exporting and binding three remote objects from the class SomeStub. We can see one real example here (from Oracle): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every time when I create and bind (`registry.rebind(...)`) one object of `SomeStub` I am creating a new `ServerSocket` to listen calls only for this object?

No. Every time you export a new remote object RMI attempts to do port sharing, and creates a new `ServerSocket` only if it doesn't already have one it can share with the new object.

Binding has nothing to do with it.

NB **This is not a stub**. It is a remote object, and it has its own stub created by RMI. Don't misuse standard naming. Call it something else.

> So if the question 1 is true

It isn't.

> is better use just only one stub of this object and threads to avoid create lots of serversockets

No.

Comment: Oh sorry they usually call it Servant not Stub, so the right is SomeServant (or SomeImp). Thanks for your reply, now i can continue my studies!

Comment: Yes. They call them Servants in CORBA. When I started in RMI 21 years ago I just called them XXXServer, but every man and his dog seems to call them XXXImpl, starting with Sun (e.g. `RegistryImpl`). Never fancied it much meself.